# Juice from chicken sous vide

Tags: chicken, sous-vide, storage

Regarding storage of sous vide chicken breasts. Should I store the cooked chicken with its juices (olive oil and chicken juices), or should I remove the breasts from the zip bag, wrap it in film, and store it that way?

Storage is refrigeration.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it either way, but I typically go for convenience.  Remove protein from water bath. Leave in bag. Allow to rest on counter for 15 - 20 minutes. Chill in ice bath.  Refrigerate or freeze. I deal with the contents of the bag at the end.

Comment: Unless there's something in the bag that may develop off flavours over a longer storage time, I'm with you as far as convenience etc. goes.